# OSX skip word shortcut no longer working

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2

Using OSX Mavericks on a rMBP, I've been working in Sublime Text 2. All of a sudden, the skip word shortcut is no longer working. I've tried:

- resetting my computer
- running `killall Dock`
- resetting Sublime Text
- reinstall Sublime Text

None have worked. In a few other places I'm noticing the shortcut isn't working too - it used to work in Chrome's address bar, now it does not. But in other places (like this text box, and Terminal) it works just fine.

Can't find any discussion on this anywhere on the web. Really confused as to what's going on, any ideas?

Comment: for the uninformed among us, what exactly is the "skip word" shortcut on OS X?

Comment: Sorry, it's option + left / right

Comment: Any luck? This just happened to me today.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue this week. I traced it back to a few web apps that I converted to "native apps" using [Nativefier](https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier) which is essentially an [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) wrapper.

I tried rebooting the machine first but since all of my apps re-opened on startup the problem persisted.  After failing to find any macOS settings for this, I started closing apps and noticed that it came back as soon as I closed my "nativified" Gmail client.  Quitting the app resolved the problem, re-opening it made it reoccur.  Same issue with google calendar.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you are using uon-U.S. input sources? If you are using `Unicode Hex Input`(or something equivalent), option-arrow would not work, while inputting alphabet works

Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources (I'm using Yosemite)

[image: OS X Preferences screenshot]